# How do I set multiple elements' css in one page without the :not attribute?

Tags: css

Recently I discovered the `:not` attribute in CSS. It's not a huge deal that it's not recognized in all browsers and has worked in most situations, but it now seems that I'm overusing it and I don't know how to stop. My CSS ends up looking a mess.

```
#div input:not(.custom-combobox-input):not(.k-input):not([type='button']):not(#coordinates>input), select 
{
    width:200px !important;
    text-indent: .33em;
    border-radius:4px;
    height:24px;
}
```

**What's a better way to set CSS properties on elements that you will have many different versions of in the same page?**

Comment: Add a specific class to the elements you want treated differently and then apply the CSS to that new specific class.

Comment: The selector in the question exemplifies how you can combine `:not` selectors to create a “not A and not B and not C...” selector. There is no other way to do that. If you want to know whether some specific situation can be addressed using some other kind of selectors, you need to describe that situation. If you want to ask meaningfully for “better way”, you also need to specify your criteria for evaluating ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a good practice to use a base class which carries all the style rules which all the elements have in common, then start customizing certain elements by adding a second class. Imagine you have a `.message`-element that delivers system messages to the user. These messages can be for pure information purposes (hints), they can tell the user taht something has worked fine, they can hold warning messages and sometimes even error messages. For this use case I'd suggest the following:

```css
.message {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  margin: 30px;
}

.message.confirmation {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.message.warning {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.message.error {
  background-color: #a00;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">Message with no special meaning or styling.</div>
<div class="message confirmation">You've done it!</div>
<div class="message warning">Please check your configuration, something seems to be odd.</div>
<div class="message error">You've got it all wrong!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `not` then use different class:

```
.different_class
{
    width:200px !important;
    text-indent: .33em;
    border-radius:4px;
    height:24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your default styling:

```
#div input, select {
    width:200px;
    text-indent: .33em;
    border-radius:4px;
    height:24px;
}
```

Followed by specific style overrides:

```
#div input.custom-combobox-input {
    width:auto;
    text-indent:0;
    border-radius:0px;
    height:auto;
}
#div .k-input {}
#div [type='button'] {}
#coordinates>input {}
```

Try to avoid `!important` declarations.

Comment: It's good advice to avoid lifting the specificity of a rule by using `!important`. Usage of it in most cases shows problems understanding and making use of css specificity resulting in structural problems. I'd even go further and recommend (almost) never to use ids for css selector purposes because you cannot overwrite style rules then without using either the same id in the selector or using !important.